# Async on Bot Framework prompt.choice

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, botframework

So, I'm trying to make a bot in Bot Framework that will retrieve information from an API and let the user to pick from that information. The problem is that I tried a lot of methods of get that information and none worked.

This is my code without async or await

```
function(session){
      servicesJSON = get.getServices(par, (res) => {});
      for (var k= 0;k<Object.keys(servicess).length; k++){
        services[k] = servicesComplete[k].name;
      }
      builder.Prompts.choice(builder, session, 'Which service do you want?', services); //this has to be sync
},
```

Then I tried to wrap the waterfall function from Bot Framework in an async function and "await" for servicesJSON

```
async function(session){
      servicesJSON = await get.getServices(par , (res) => {});
      for (var k= 0;k<Object.keys(servicess).length-2; k++){
        services[k] = servicesComplete[k].name;
      }
      builder.Prompts.choice(builder, session, 'Which service do you want?', services); //this has to be sync
},
```

But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callback you aren't returning anything, have you tried this:

```
servicesJSON = await get.getServices(par , (res) => res);
```